# Git diff different from diff-tree. How to do diff-tree in jgit?

Tags: git, bitbucket, jgit

I am using JGit to evaluate the affected files between to commit ids. The code I set up is in line with the jgit cookbook.

https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/DiffFilesInCommit.java

I basically look up the commit ID im interested in and the one immediately before that using git log. I then stuff those into the code example.

The problem is that it comes back with a lot of files that weren't touched or added as part of this commit, which should be only 2.

If I run a `git diff HASH1 HASH2` I get the same result with tons of files that weren't touched.

Conversely when running `git diff-tree -r HASH1` I get exactly the 2 files I'm interested in.

Am I misunderstanding something? How are git diff and diff-tree different? How can I replicate the behavior of git diff-tree using jgit?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just answered it.

Instead of looking up the previous commit id from the history the previous commit id should be the one I'm interested in suffixed with a ~1.

```
git diff HASH1 HASH1~1
```